# Replace only the first occurrence of a word with regex in text-editor

Tags: regex, replace, gedit, regex-lookarounds

I want to replace only first occurrence of word(default) in each line with another word(rwd).

As below I want this:

```
../app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/pmodule.xml
../app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/pmodule.xml
../app/design/frontend/default/default/template/company/module/gmap.phtml
```

To be replaced to this:

```
../app/design/adminhtml/rwd/default/layout/pmodule.xml
../app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/pmodule.xml
../app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/company/module/gmap.phtml
```

I have tried `\bdefault\b` but in vain.

Comment: Gedit 3.10.4 in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Doesn't [`^(.*?)\bdefault\b` --> `\1rwd`](https://regex101.com/r/nJ3hO0/1) work? I think lazy matching here is a much better solution than a tempered greedy token suggested in the answer below.

Comment: Or you can try [`\bdefault\b(.*)` and replace with `rwd\1`](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5lM7/1) (similar wiktors answer)

Answer (score 9):

You can use a regex with a lazy dot matching pattern:

```
^(.*?)\bdefault\b
```

To replace with `\1rwd`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ3hO0/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line/string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ characters other than a newline as few as possible up to the first
- `\bdefault\b` -  whole word `default`.

GEdit screenshot:

[image]

Geany screenshot:

[image]

Comment: In geany this works fine, but in Gedit, it adds some newlines creating blank lines in between.

Comment: It is really strange. The pattern does not match a newline at all (if the DOTALL option is OFF in GEdit).

Comment: Ok, got it, probably it is on, I will check and confirm tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: No it's not working, I just tried this in Geany, it's replacing all occurrences of word `default` to `rwd`, but I just want to replace first occurrence of the ord `default`. It's not complying to my requirements.

Comment: The first occurrence on a line or in the whole string? In Notepad++, it works so that the first occurrence on a line is replaced. Actually, `.*?` is equivalent of the tempered gredy token suggested by anubhava. Just my expression should be faster.

Comment: Yes so it is contradictory, in demo you have `/gm` as regex flags but it doesn't work if multiline mode is enabled. In geany when I turned multiline off it did work.

Comment: @VickyDev There is nothing contradictory if you mean the demo at regex101.com. `m` stands for `MULTILINE` option that makes `^` match start of any line and `$` match end of  any line. This mode is enabled by default in text editors, you never need to specify the `m` flag there. I added GEdit and Geany screenshots proving my solution works.

Answer (score 2):

You can search using this lookahead regex:

```
^((?:(?!\bdefault\b).)*)default
```

And replace it using:

```
\1rwd
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE5jD3/1)

Comment: Have you tried this in Gedit, it doesn't work in that.

Comment: I don't have gedit but checked online that gedit allows lookahead

Comment: Ok, so I have to check how to enable lookahead in Gedit. Will do that tomorrow in office.

Comment: It's working in other editors like Geany, Notepad++ etc., so +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var path = @"C:\Users\pcNameHere\Downloads\dictionary.csv";
        var destination = @"C:\Users\pcNameHere\Downloads\dictionaryEnglish.csv";
        var database = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        var pattern = ",";
        Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
        string[] result = new string[database.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < database.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = reg.Replace(database[i], "|", 2);
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(destination, result);
```

Here is my sample for anyone looking in the future. I had the English dictionary text file with lines like these:

```
"Abacus","n.","A table or tray strewn with sand, anciently used for drawing, calculating, etc."
```

And I had to replace comma delimiters with something else so I could import them into a database, because there were commas inside the word definitions and the database would treat them as new columns. This code changed the first two occurrences of a comma in each line in the text file.